# Mongo C# Driver OData issue "Where with predicate after a project is not supported"

Tags: mongodb, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, odata

Request: /api/person?$filter Name eq 'John' with server backed up method that 
return repo.GetAll().Select(o => Mapper.Map<>PersonDTO>(o));

Only the $filter requests error out with "Where with predicate after a project is not supported" but $top / $skip / $orderby work fine. My guess is, Mongo C# has a bug while generating the query & projects before applying the filter. Instead it should apply filter first and then project. I am using OData 5.2.0-rc1 and Mongo C# driver is 1.7.

Any inputs are much appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: Have you checked the [source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver)? The official docs don't mention support for this. There are a few open source odata implementations you could look at.

Answer (score 0):

That is a limitation in the current implementation of Linq.  We are working to correct that with this ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-601.

However, I'd encourage you to figure out what you are actually attempting to do.  Projecting prior to a filter could mean you are filtering on computed expressions, such as adding 2 columns together.  MongoDB queries do not support this type of behavior, which is why this is currently disallowed by our linq provider.  Aggregation framework allows this to a point, but there are a different set of limitations imposed by the Aggregation framework.

In your particular case, what you are wanting us to do is impossible.  You are asking us to know how to create a MongoDB query based on an AutoMapper generated object.  This simply impossible unless we (at runtime) read the AutoMapper mapping and apply it to our internal class models.